# TensorBoard + tensorflow.slim working together

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow-slim

On low level tensorflow API, I can plot a histogram for example using the following code

```
.. some code ..
with tf.name_scope('output_layer'):
    weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([d1, d2], dtype=tf.float32),
                          name='weights')
    biases = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([d2], dtype=tf.float32), 
                         name='biases')

tf.summary.histogram('output_weights', weights)
tf.summary.histogram('biases', biases)
```

Recently I decided to try out the `slim` API, and I was wondering how can I manage my TensorBoard plots in simple, and more complex cases.

For example, if I would like to plot the histogram (as `tf.summary.histogram`) of the weights and the mean (as `tf.summary.scalar`) of biases in the following two examples, what would I do?

Simple example:

```
with tf.name_scope('output_layer'):
    predictions = slim.fully_connected(inputs, d2)
```

Complex example:

```
with tf.name_scope('output_layer'):
    predictions = slim.stack(inputs, slim.fully_connected, [32, 64, 128])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the standard way of doing this is having a loop like this, which will add distributions and histograms of weights, biases, batch-norm parameters etc, for each layer:

```
for variable in slim.get_model_variables():
    tf.summary.histogram(variable.op.name, variable)
```

Comment: How would I get the mean of the weights in this way? This simply try to histogram every trainable variable in the graph...

Comment: The above solution will provide **one histogram for each layer** of weights, which is one (multi-dimensional) variable in the end -- this is what you are trying to do, right?

Comment: Nope, I said in the question if I want to get for example the MEAN of the weights - or any other transformation on specific set of variables

Comment: Are you aware of the distribution dashboard? If the median is fine for you this will already show up there (using the code above). Otherwise, simply perform the operations you wish on the variable, like `tf.reduce_mean`.

Comment: I took the mean for an example. Yes I would like to run things like `reduce_mean` but for that I need to access things specifically. So if you take into consideration my complex example, how would you get the mean of the second layer's weights? And I'm aware of the dashboard - as I said its just an example I might as well be calculating their l2 norm